# How to Remotely Retrieve Password Hash from Computer

Tags: password-cracking, macos

Just for fun, I wanted to see if I could remotely extract the password hash of my own user account on my own Mac.

Assume that the device is running either the latest version of macOS Sierra (10.12.6) or High Sierra (10.13.3). Also, assume that the computer has remote management and SSH enabled. The only catch is that SSH is set to not allow any user to authenticate.

Knowing this, is there any way that I could remotely grab the password hash of my local account to attempt to crack it on another PC?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to remotely access a system outside of SSH. Hint: look at the sharing tab in your sys pref. Don't forget about VNC and 3rd party tools (LogMeIn, etc.).

Also, if you are considering network layer attacks, you can use network spoofing attacks for Directory-based auth protocols. See [Responder](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/Responder) as an example (mainly for Windows netNTLM hashes via NBT-NS and LLMNR, but OSX can support these as well if in a Windows Enterprise environment).

> Supports NTLMv1, NTLMv2 hashes with Extended Security NTLMSSP by
>   default. Successfully tested from Windows 95 to Server 2012 RC, Samba
>   and Mac OSX Lion. Clear text password is supported for NT4, and LM
>   hashing downgrade when the --lm option is set. This functionality is
>   enabled by default when the tool is launched.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! What is an example of a way to get a password hash of a system with VNC enabled?

Comment: It depends on the version of OSX, but given the OS in your question, have a look here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220729/what-type-of-hash-are-a-macs-password-stored-in/220863